# Deploy de projeto Laravel pelo Git

Tags: php, laravel, git, laravel-5, composer

Preciso fazer deploy de um projeto Laravel instalado num dev pc em um servidor Linux.

Depois de baixar tudo via Git, algumas pastas estão ignoradas pelo `.gitignore`.

Como mando rodar o Composer para reinstalar todas as dependências? Tem npm também?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode seguir o tutorial para a instalação e configuração do laravel aqui na [documentação oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2).

Levando em consideração que você tenha `php` e `composer` na sua variável global `PATH`, para uma nova instalação do Laravel, execute:

`composer create-project laravel/laravel nome-do-seu-projeto --prefer-dist`

---

#### Clonando um projeto e instalando o Laravel

Vou novamente considerar que você esteja rodando um sistema operacional `Linux` e com o `git` instalado, faça o seguinte:

#### Clone o projeto

`git clone git@github.com:seuprojeto`

#### Acesse o projeto

`cd seuprojeto`

#### Instale as dependências e o framework

`composer install --no-scripts`

#### Copie o arquivo .env.example

`cp .env.example .env`

#### Crie uma nova chave para a aplicação

`php artisan key:generate`

Em seguida você deve configurar o arquivo .env e rodar as migrations com:

`php artisan migrate --seed`

Em relação ao npm, isso varia de projeto para projeto, mas provavelmente você também vai precisar rodar os seguintes comandos:

`npm install`

`bower install`

`gulp`

Se você não faz idéia do que significa estes comandos, sugiro que comece a estudar um a um antes de colocar uma aplicação em produção. A documentação oficial do `Laravel 5.2` contém dois projetos exemplos desenvolvido passo-a-passo, não é uma má idéia iniciar por ai, está em inglês mas o texto é de fácil leitura.